# Selecting multiple dates with Vuetify

Tags: vue.js, datepicker, vuejs3, nuxt.js, vuetify.js

```
const date = ref(new Date(2024, 1, 19)) 
<v-date-picker v-model="date" :rows="2" :step="1" class="bg-surface" locale="tr" />
```

[image: Image of my current date picker]

I am using Vue.js, Nuxt.js, and Vuetify. I want to show more than one selected date in the date picker. I tried the Multiple feature but it didn't work. Can you help?

Comment: "_I tried the Multiple feature but it didn't work_" what did you try?  According to the documention it just needs the `multiple` prop and of course a v-model that is an array.  [example demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNpVjs0KgzAQhF9l2YsKjb8V2qJCoW+hHoquIDUmJNEexHdvYi/tbXZ29putN9Sqi+5ShutCeMPCEJfT01DVzADFynqrmRy7FylYGRc9TWWDztUNAl8mM8qJqiL6i9rrIvpB2VF3apQGNJlFHvCRS6EMbKBogB0GJTh49gvPLTsxawNHDZQu4dczveFhDd9L4+TC4ozFqRe0gav6wi0W9xNm4TlMruhEHubYfgCZyksL)

Comment: @yoduh Thank you. But when I write it with typescript it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?


`const dates: Date[] = [
    new Date("2024-01-16"),
    new Date("2024-01-25"),
    new Date("2024-01-12")
];
<v-date-picker v-model="dates" multiple locale="tr"></v-date-picker>`

Comment: You removed `ref` from the variable.  `ref` is needed to make the variable reactive, and also because without it you're causing reassignment of a const.  [updated demo](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#eNp1TsGqwjAQ/JVlLyqY1vbZB2osCP5F04PUVYpJG5K0HsR/d6MXBb3N7MzOTHVD75p0Z20yDoRrlIGM1YdApeoA5CiOjIVtmws5GIXpj6S3CuPVKwQz6NBaTaVMP6z8LdO3KKa+ca0N4CkMFvShO3NM4IxnUWts7wLcwNEJ7nByvYEJL5pEsek7H+BZCdvokHvGVV1Oq46uEMlUYb7Il2KRiexf4WwOX5S8+KVkOSv1bBNXv3byKrzP8S9ZJtkKIyiSAusHBiJfWA==)

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed it.

You have to use the range prop, then put two dates in an array then v-model that array

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    date: ['2018-03-02', '2018-03-07']
  }),
})

<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-row justify="center">
      <v-date-picker
        v-model="date"
        range=true
      ></v-date-picker>
    </v-row>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

[Codepen date range](https://codepen.io/James-Mann/pen/NWmKKRe?editors=101)